# How to edit text of ActiveX TextBox on Excel by Python using xlwings?

Tags: python, excel, pywin32, win32com, xlwings

I'm trying to edit text of ActiveX TextBox on Excel by python using xlwing.
How to edit it?

I successed to edit text of normal TexBox like this.

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book('test.xlsx')
sheet = wb.sheets['Sheet1']
textbox = sheet.api.TextBoxes('TextBox1')
textbox .Text = 'test'
```

I tried some but I couldn't edit text of ActiveX TextBox.

Comment: this might help: https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/8

Answer (score 0):

test it

```
sheet.api.OLEObjects("TextBox1").Object.Value = "some value"
```

Regards

Josse